# Do I need to explicitly enable jumbo frames in NFSv4?

Tags: networking, nfs, high-performance

I'm using NFS to share data between VMs. I've already set up working jumbo frames between VMs and host. My question is - do I need to somehow explicitly tell nfs to use jumbo frames or it'll just detect possibility of using them automatically?

All network interfaces have MTU set to 9000. `ping -M do -s 8000` work flawlessly.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but in my experience `ssh` is extremely sensitive to problems that can arise when jumbo frames are used and it's also really easy to test for jumbo frame problems with `ssh`:  simply `ssh` to a server across a network that's supposed to use jumbo frames and try to `cat` a *large* text file.  If your `ssh` session hangs, you almost certainly have a problem with you network's implementation of jumbo frames.

Comment: You wouldn't believe but just 2 minutes ago I finished troubleshooting for like 6h not working ssh after enabling jumbo frames xD. Indeed it seems to be really sensitive. I had even less luck. It didn't hang - it just didn't work at all when i tried to connect from WAN. Completely deaf no prompt for password, nothing. Yet in LAN worked flawlessly. Turns out I changed gateway port in one of routers and forgot to change MTU as well...

Comment: SSH should not have any business here, ideally Jumbo frames should be setup on a dedicated network/VLAN only for dealing with storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mount the nfs filesystem with the `rsize` and `wsize` options set to suitable values. Check `man nfs`.